# iOS In-App Purchasing step by step tutorial

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Is there any step by step source code/video or any other kind of help to implement in-app-purchasing ? I have tried many tutorials but still i am not able to get perfect solution for the in-app-purchasing..

What is the use of shared secret key?

Comment: Check the below link for the step by step tutorial with source code. http://maniacdev.com/2010/09/tutorial-in-app-purchase/ http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/02/things-i-learned-implementing-my-first-inapppurchase/ http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/ http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/ **Recommended** http://nixsolutions.com/blog/development/iphone/in-app-purchase-tutorial/

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS in-app purchase sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178214/ios-in-app-purchase-sample-code)

Comment: I've used a very good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial). I'm recommending it for you.

Comment: check this link i think it is good for in-app purchase http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_In-App_Purchase_Tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556336/how-do-you-add-a-in-app-purchase-to-an-iphone-application http://www.codetuition.com/ios-tutorials/integrating-ios-app-with-in-app-purchase/ and also video link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CiZz_up5Gkg

Comment: you can visit this link that contain sample code and detailed description [In App purchase in iOS](http://iosbucket.blogspot.in/2015/06/in-app-purchase-in-ios.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add an in-app purchase to an iOS application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556336/how-do-you-add-an-in-app-purchase-to-an-ios-application)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that the best guide ever is the official [In App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html), since it's full of examples, piece of codes, hints and so on. Following and reading carefully the Guide will surely help you in writing a fully functional test project.

In the meanwhile you could want to look at the [MKStoreKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit) v4 add-on for your project to help you handle your in-app purchases in a easier way.

Comment: It is really very nice tutorial I am successfully able to test In-App-Purchasing but after first time I am unable to test In-App-Purchasing why? Can any one help me..Thank you

Comment: I really don't know. You'd better contact Apple Support for such problems, they are really kind and will surely help you solve that kind of problems.