# Error with adding in-app purchases - Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, in-app-purchase

I used info from [this brilliant page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556336/how-do-you-add-a-in-app-purchase-to-an-iphone-application) to add in-app purchases.

However I get the NSLog `No Product Available`. I have checked to make sure I have added the correct `Product ID`. I am at a loss to what to do and have been at this for several hours.

This is for a game built on Cocos2d and I can't figure out what is wrong. Sorry for the abundance of code. 
I have added `<SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>` and `<StoreKit/StoreKit.h>`

**.m**

```
#define kRemoveAdsProductIdentifier @"COINS1000"

@implementation shopCoins

- (void)buy500Coins{

    NSLog(@"User requests to remove ads");

    if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
        NSLog(@"User can make payments");

        SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:kRemoveAdsProductIdentifier]];
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        [productsRequest start];

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"User cannot make payments due to parental controls");
        //this is called the user cannot make payments, most likely due to parental controls
    }
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    int count = [response.products count];
    if(count > 0){
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Products Available!");
        [self purchase:validProduct];
    }
    else if(!validProduct){
        NSLog(@"No products available");
        //this is called if your product id is not valid, this shouldn't be called unless that happens.
    }
}

- (IBAction)purchase:(SKProduct *)product{
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (IBAction) restore{
    //this is called when the user restores purchases, you should hook this up to a button
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        if(SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored){
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
            //called when the user successfully restores a purchase
            [self doRemoveAds];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        }

    }

}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
        switch (transaction.transactionState){
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchasing");
                //called when the user is in the process of purchasing, do not add any of your own code here.
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                //this is called when the user has successfully purchased the package (Cha-Ching!)

                [self doRemoveAds]; //you can add your code for what you want to happen when the user buys the purchase here, for this tutorial we use removing ads
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchased");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
                //add the same code as you did from SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased here
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                //called when the transaction does not finnish
                if(transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled){
                    NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Cancelled");
                    //the user cancelled the payment ;(
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)doRemoveAds{

    NSLog(@"Bitches");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a debug build you probably need to add a sandbox user on iTunes connect this will allow you to use IAP that have not been reviewed yet. Note this user should match your iTunes connect account.

Comment: Have you run through the Apple in-app purchase programming guide? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267

Comment: Also worth checking your bundle identifier and provisions match up.