# IAP in iOS app without developer account

Tags: ios, sdk, in-app-purchase

I don't have a developer account of Apple, but I want to implement IAP. Is it possible to download SDK, see instructions in documentation how to integrate and test it on simulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: It's not possible to test IAPs without a developer account.

In order to test an in-app purchase, you must have an *in-app purchase identifier* registered in the Member Center of Apple's Developer Portal for your app. Without this, your app won't be able to download a list of available products or process test transactions. In addition, you'll need to attempt the purchase through a test account created in iTunes Connect. You'll need to register as a developer if you want to test in-app purchases. (Sidenote: The simulator does not support the `StoreKit` framework, you have to test it on an actual device.)

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19556337/1145804) may also help you. However, when you do start programming IAPs, I'd recommend [RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore) as a great library to use.

Comment: @OK Jobs forces me to buy not only Mac, but also iPhone and developer account. Just great! The same is for push notifications, right?

Comment: Yep, same for push notifications lol. It's generally better to test on the actual device anyway because simulator doesn't do a great job finding things like lag if there is any

Comment: It's possible now, please check the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54295578/test-in-app-purchases-without-a-developer-account/71598281#:~:text=Well%20It%27s%20Possible%20now%2C