# Test in-app-purchases without a developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

it is possible to test in-app-purchases for development testing without a developer account? I can´t access sanbox and Features without being a developer member in itunes connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's NOT possible.

Here is the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

Answer (score 3):

No it's most definitely not possible. You will require a registered developer account.

Answer (score 1):

Well It's Possible now,

From the source [https://medium.com/globant/wwdc-2020-announcement-view-from-a-developers-eye-c94770e85b09#:~:text=StoreKit%20Testing%20in%20Xcode%2D12](https://medium.com/globant/wwdc-2020-announcement-view-from-a-developers-eye-c94770e85b09#:%7E:text=StoreKit%20Testing%20in%20Xcode%2D12)

**Major highlights are:**

- A local environment for testing your in-app purchases without needing to connect to App Store servers.
- Set up a test environment, create a StoreKit configuration file, and prepare to validate receipts locally.
- Test a variety of in-app purchase scenarios and automate those tests (like success purchase, failed purchase, interrupted purchase, external transactions, and Subscription offers) with the StoreKitTest framework.
  Improvements for testing in the sandbox environment.
- You can test it in all the simulators of iOS 14, tvOS 14, watch OS 7, mac OS Big Sur as well as on the physical devices.
- Create unit & UI tests with XCTest
  You have full control of the StoreKit in the Xcode environment without user interaction.
- You can trigger the renewal of the subscription for testing the scenarios offline.

For more details please check: Apple documentation
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/setting-up-storekit-testing-in-xcode
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekittest
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10659/

PS: New Testing StoreKit in a macOS app requires Xcode 12 or later running on macOS 11 or later.