# Adding more in-app purchases

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit

I followed [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556336/how-do-you-add-a-in-app-purchase-to-an-iphone-application) to help me add in-app purchases. It works well, except now I am trying to add another non-consumable IAP. I defined my second product ID and created a method for the purchase button, but I'm not sure if I have to create another SKProductsRequest for this extra item, or if I use the same one, etc...

Here is my full code.

```
#define kRemoveAdsProductIdentifier @"099"
#define kDoubleEarningRateProductIdentifer @"199"

- (void)removeAds{
    NSLog(@"User requests to remove ads");

    if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
        NSLog(@"User can make payments");

        SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:kRemoveAdsProductIdentifier]];
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        [productsRequest start];

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"User cannot make payments due to parental controls");
        //this is called the user cannot make payments, most likely due to parental controls
    }
}

- (void)doubleEarningRate{
    NSLog(@"User requests 2x earning rate");

    if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
        NSLog(@"User can make payments");

        SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:kDoubleEarningRateProductIdentifer]];
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        [productsRequest start];

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"User cannot make payments due to parental controls");
        //this is called the user cannot make payments, most likely due to parental controls
    }
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    int count = [response.products count];
    if(count > 0){
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Products Available!");
        [self purchase:validProduct];
    }
    else if(!validProduct){
        NSLog(@"No products available");
        //this is called if your product id is not valid, this shouldn't be called unless that happens.
    }
}

- (void)purchase:(SKProduct *)product{
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (void) restore{
    //this is called when the user restores purchases, you should hook this up to a button
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        if(SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored){
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
            //called when the user successfully restores a purchase
            [self doRemoveAds];
            [self doubleEarningRate];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        }

    }

}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
        switch (transaction.transactionState){
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchasing");
                //called when the user is in the process of purchasing, do not add any of your own code here.
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                //this is called when the user has successfully purchased the package (Cha-Ching!)

                [self doRemoveAds]; //you can add your code for what you want to happen when the user buys the purchase here, for this tutorial we use removing ads
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchased");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
                //add the same code as you did from SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased here
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                //called when the transaction does not finnish
                if(transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled){
                    NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Cancelled");
                    //the user cancelled the payment ;(
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
        }
    }
}



-(void)doRemoveAds
{
    areAdsRemoved = true;
    NSLog(@"Ads Removed");
    [topBanner removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void)doDoubleEarningRate
{

}
```

I also read through apple documentation which explained to me what each part does, but I am still clueless on how I can add another purchase, and most other tutorials are done differently or outdated. Also all the variables and indirection is a bit intimidating to me. So I am hoping that someone can give me a quick step by step guide for adding another purchase.

To make it clearer, this approach works perfectly for just one in app purchase. However I don't know how to add more, as in I don't know how to make the program recognize which in-app purchase is being selected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a method called `provideContent:(NSString *)productId`. Then you can either use a switch statement or if statement to differentiate between product Id's. No need to create multiple types of productRequest methods, etc...