# No products being returned from iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store-connect

I've been searching stackoverflow for several days on how to get products to return from itunes connect. I've found a lot of information, and have tried to follow it. However, I just cannot get any products to return in the SKProductsResponse. 
I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 
I have tried deleting and re-adding products. 
I have tried this with the emulator and with my iPhone 5.
I have waited for 24 hours to see if that would cause the product to appear. Nothing. 

Here is the process I follow each time:

1. in developer.apple.com:

   1. check that I have a valid iOS Development certificate
   2. my iOS device (iPhone 5) is registered
   3. create a new app id

      1. used explicit app id with bundle id: com.ftotech.iaptest01
      2. in-app purchase checkmark is checked in App Services
   4. create a new provisioning profile

      1. iOS App Development type of provisioning profile
      2. selected App ID created above
      3. selected my iOS development certificate
      4. selected my iOS device
      5. named the profile the same as the bundle id: com.ftotech.iaptest01
   5. The provisioning profile shows status Active
2. create icon PNGs with following resolutions, without alpha channels:

   1. 1024x1024
   2. 76x76
   3. 120x102
   4. 152x152
3. create screen shot PNGs with following resolutions, without alpha channels:

   1. 640x920 for 3.5-inch
   2. 750x1334 for 4.7-inch
   3. 640x1096 for 4-inch
   4. 1242x2208 for 5.5-inch
   5. 1024x748 for iPad
   6. 640x920 for product
4. create new single-view project in Xcode: iaptest01

   1. in project settings, General, identity section:

      1. verified that bundle id is com.ftotech.iaptest01
      2. No signing identity found error, so clicked fix issue button, selected my development team
      3. error disappeared
   2. in project settings, General, Linked Frameworks and Libraries section, added StoreKit.framework
   3. in project settings, Capabilities section, verified that the in-app purchase item is ON and the two steps (link stoker.framework and add in-app purchase entitlement) are checked
   4. Add icons to asset catalog:

      1. drag 76x76 icon to ipad app 1x
      2. drag 120x120 icon to iphone app 2x
      3. drag 152x152 icon to ipad app 2x
   5. In storyboard, added a single label, centered at the top and added an outlet named labelProduct
   6. ViewController.h below
   7. ViewController.m below
   8. Archive app and submit - successful
5. create new iOS App in iTunes Connect

   1. selected bundle ID com.ftotech.iaptest01
   2. complete pricing section
   3. on in-app purchase section, create a consumable product

      1. product ID:com.ftotech.iaptest01.product1
      2. cleared for sale - Yes
      3. set Language settings
      4. added screenshot
      5. product show status of “Ready to Submit"
   4. on the versions section

      1. complete all needed fields
      2. upload screenshots and icon
      3. add the product to the in-app purchases section
      4. add the build to the build section
   5. submitted for review - this was successful, and it is now waiting for review

ViewController.m:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  iaptest01
//
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                             initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:
                               UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityIndicatorView.center = self.view.center;
    [activityIndicatorView hidesWhenStopped];
    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicatorView];
    [activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
    [self fetchAvailableProducts];
}

-(void)fetchAvailableProducts{
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet
                                 setWithObjects:@"com.ftotech.iaptest01.product1", 
                                 nil];
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                       initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request
    didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    int count = (int)[response.products count];
    [_labelProduct setText:response.description];
    if ( count > 0 ) {
        validProducts = response.products;
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
        [_labelProduct setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                @"found product: %@",validProduct.localizedTitle]];
        UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Available"
                            message:@"Found products"
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [tmp show];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Not Available"
                            message:[@"No products: " stringByAppendingString:
                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count]]
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [tmp show];
    }
    NSArray *products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

    for (SKProduct *product in products)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product not found: %@", product);
    }

    [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

ViewController.h:

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  iaptest01
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<SKProductsRequestDelegate>
{
    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;
    NSArray *validProducts;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelProduct;

- (void)fetchAvailableProducts;

@end
```

Can anyone see a step I'm missing or something that I've configured incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Would [this extremely thorough answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19556337/300836) help? In particular, you don't seem to mention creating a test user at any point, which I'm guessing means you won't see unapproved products?

Comment: It appears that the test user is for making (dummy) purchases. Retrieving the products does not seem to require a test user account. This makes sense, because you shouldn't have to log in to simply get the list of products. However, thank you for that link. I'll scour it for possible answers.

Comment: After looking through the link that Matt Gibson suggested, I added some code to list the invalid products from the request. This prompted me to look again at my products in iTunes Connect. The product is "Waiting for Review" which seems odd. I clicked the product, and there is a message at the top: "You do not currently have a iOS Paid Apps contract in effect." I had ignored this previously. Maybe that's the problem. I've completed the bank and tax information, and the contract is processing. Once that finishes, maybe the products will show up?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my banking and tax information was not complete.
In order for the above process to work, go to the "Agreements, Tax and Banking" area in iTunes Connect and verify that the "iOS Paid Applications" contract is in effect.
It took about 15 minutes after completing the information, but as soon as the contract was in effect, the product was correctly returned by SKProductsResponse.
Thank you Matt Gibson for the tip that started me on the path to the solution!
BTW, it DOES work in the iOS Simulator 8.1.