# UIButton error with SKPayment

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase, ibaction, skpaymenttransaction

I used this tutorial [How do you add an in-app purchase to an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556336/how-do-you-add-an-in-app-purchase-to-an-ios-application) for SKPayment (verbatim) and I am having trouble linking the purchase buttons on my storyboard to my code.

```
- (IBAction)purchase:(SKProduct *)product{
```

I keep getting the following error.

```
[UIButton productIdentifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffa08cfbe90
```

I understand that the tutorial uses a xib file but I am using a storyboard file for my game to link the buttons. Can somebody please tell me how I would link my purchase button in my storyboard to the

```
- (IBAction)purchase:(SKProduct *)product{
```

code without getting an unrecognized selector error?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `IBAction` expects a `sender` as its first parameter.
And when it's "linked" to a `UIButton`, that `UIButton` is the `sender` (it's automatically sent).
That why you get the error, `UIButton` doesn't know the selector `productIdentifier`.

If you look carefully to the answer your linked on SO, the methods linked to IB aren't this one. This one is called with `[self purchase:someSKProduct]`, that's why it's not causing the crash on his/her code.

Well, I haven't played with StoreKitFramework, but it seems that this method shouldn't be an IBAction (either here on on the answer, it's confusing, proof: your current issue.).
It should be just `-(void)purchase:(SKProduct *)product`.

Comment: I tried adding `-(void)purchase:(SKProduct *)product` to my code and running the method in my IBAction method, but I'm not sure what to replace the SKProduct object with within the IBAction Method, hence: `[self purchase:(SKProduct *)`

Comment: How do you define the product? Which SKProduct is it? Maybe have a look of how the linked answer does

Comment: Per the code from the tutorial, It's not defined globally it's only defined locally to its method.  `- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;`

Comment: And it's a place filler object here. `- (IBAction)purchase:(SKProduct *)product{
    
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];`

Comment: Do you have any idea of how I can I fix this? @Larme

Comment: Then do the same. At the same place if you call it, it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You should link your purchase button to `(IBAction)tapsRemoveAds`.

And like what Larme said, you should change:

```
(IBAction)purchase:(SKProduct *)product
```

to

```
(void)purchase:(SKProduct *)product
```