# inAppPurchase in ios SDK using xcode6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, in-app-purchase

I want to test in-App-Purchase

What I have done:

1.Created Certificate/AppId/Provisioning

2.Bundle Id of my app : `com.sample.product`

3. Set Up an app in `itunesConnect`.
4. product Identifier of my app which i have to buy: `com.sample.product.buy`

I have followed and implemented all steps from here:

[steps i followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556336/how-do-you-add-an-in-app-purchase-to-an-ios-application)

No I get NSLog value : Product Not Availabel

I checked for issues like:

1. Different product id
2. Cleared for sale
3. Waited 4 days

**Why I am getting this error?**
**What I missed?**

When I open app in [itunes.connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) and select In-App-Purchase am getting this message at the top of screen:

[image]

Is it OKAY ? Or due this warning message I am getting **Product Not Available** message ?

Answer (score 1):

Open itunes connect.
Select Agreement, Tax,and Banking tab.
Add your bank account details for "Paid Applications" than above waring will not appear.

[image]

Comment: you definitely cannot test in-app purchases until you have set up your banking info.

Answer (score 0):

In-app purchase is **broadly made up** of 3 distinct steps:

1 - **Getting products from itunes store** and displaying them on UI (Store UI which displays product titles, description, price in user-understandable way)

2 - **Providing mechanism for user to purchase products** from UI (IBActions that enable "Buy" action)

3 - **Handling post-purchase** (handle successful purchase by unlocking the product, handle failed purchase by displaying user-understandable error, and handle future restore for non-consumable products as they must not be purchased again as per the rules set by Apple)

This is what you must do. And there are no set "steps" for any app. **Every app has it's own way of selling IAP items, and you must define yours.** Give ample thought about each step, instead of trying to get things working anyway. In-app purchase is fun to troubleshoot, but does not yield results if done badly. More you do it "user-friendly" & business-like way, more you benefit from it.

If you need step by step tutorial on how to integrate IAP - here is my [own tutorial](http://www.iphonegamezone.net/make-money-appstore-ios-in-app-purchase-tutorial/) to simplify what I wrote above.

If you need more efficient solution, here is [video lecture series](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-ios-moneymaking-course-learn-in-app-purchases/?couponCode=PROMO29SO) with SWIFT and Objective C. It also accompanies code sample.