# in-app purchasing: auto-renewable subscriptions?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase, device

In my app I have users subscribing to Auto-Renewable In-App Purchases. They can subscribe either 1 or 12 months.

my question is that if a user has purchased 12 months subscription from one device and suppose the device got stolen after the purchase

With new device the user login with same credentials in the application
(as now it will contain new device id ) ???

Did the user will be able to continue with the subscription, what he purchased or the user need to pay again for auto renew subscription as he/she has new device id..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a `non-consumable` in-app purchase.
Check out how to do that at [How do you add an in-app purchase to an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556336/how-do-you-add-an-in-app-purchase-to-an-ios-application)

Once you read the accepted answer you will see that your app needs a restore button which means if the user uses the same apple id with any device, your in-app purchase can be restored. There is no need for device id.

And about keeping track of time before your subscription ends. For this you should ask your user to register with their username/password and store it in your database with the subscription end date. Therefore, every time you user tries to restore in-app purchase your app can check the end subscription date in your database.