# Shoud "Agreements, Tax, and Banking" be done competely before testing my In-app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I followed a tutorial from

[How do you add an in-app purchase to an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556336/how-do-you-add-an-in-app-purchase-to-an-ios-application)

and added three In-app Purchases
[image]

However, I've waited Non-Consumable type for two days and it's not registered yet.

And for Free Subscription, it's fine.

Is it the reason I haven't completed all the details on "Agreements, Tax, and Banking" so I couldn't test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The problem here with your non-consumable iAPs is that they will earn you revenue. ANnd to start earning any revenue on iTunes Connect you have to have all contracts signed. The bank accounts aren't yet necessary, those will be needed before realising your app into production. What you can do is fill out all forms regarding taxes and contracts and then resubmit your iAPs (edit and submit or completely delete and resubmit). This should then fix it within a few hours. If there's still a problem it would be a good idea to file a radar at [The Bug Reporter.](https://bugreport.apple.com/)

You could also follow any of those tutorials

- Swift AppCoda's iAP Tutorial which can be found [here](http://www.appcoda.com/in-app-purchase-tutorial/).
- Obj-C TechTopia's iAP Tutorial which can be found [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_In-App_Purchase_Tutorial)

Hope that helps, Julian

Comment: Thanks a lot, Julian.