# in app purchase app_item_id not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am developing the InAppPurchase with Non_Renewing Subscription.from

> `[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]`

am receiving the receipt, but i am not receiving the

> { "status":0, "environment":"Sandbox", 
>       "receipt":{"receipt_type":"ProductionSandbox", "adam_id":0, **"app_item_id":0,**
>       }

i didn't get the

> **app_item_id** , always it returns **
>   "0"

**

anyone please help me to resolve my problem.
Thanks advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556336/how-do-you-add-an-in-app-purchase-to-an-ios-application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add an in-app purchase to an iOS application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556336/how-do-you-add-an-in-app-purchase-to-an-ios-application)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for App Item ID](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW16) states:

> Apps are assigned an identifier only in the production environment, so
>   this key is not present for receipts created in the test environment.

Seeing as though the receipt type is `ProductionSandbox`, you will not get an `app_item_id`.