# iPhone : InApp Purchase issue

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm new in App Developpment. I try to add In App Purchase on my app but I don't know why it's not working. I need some help.

First of all, I follow this post.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556336/how-do-you-add-an-in-app-purchase-to-an-ios-application/57131522#57131522)

All seems working, but nothing append (no windows are openned to propose Purchase, no error). So I can't make any screenshot.

ID is correct ;-)

In AppStoreConnect, I created a sandbox tester, all bank informations are ok, It's disponible for sale,...
But I can't add in "AppStore" the InAppPurchase I had created ! like Apple's help ask to do, because I don't have any section for it !
[enter link description here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev1986a0e5c)
[image]

My InAppPurchase is like this "Waiting for upload":
[image]

What should I do ?

Comment: This question is hard to understand... but so is IAP.  It seems that you may expect the IAP to work without adding any new code in your app.  There are many steps.

I would suggest trying this GitHub repo ( https://github.com/BooberBunz/In-app-purchases-on-IOS ) and if that doesn't work, then try this tutorial ( https://www.raywenderlich.com/5456-in-app-purchase-tutorial-getting-started )

Comment: thanks. I will try these tutorials