# How to create an in-app-purchase Native Module in React Native

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implementing an in-app-purchase mechanism in my React Native app for iOS.
But I couldn't found official supported modules about it, and I don't want to use any third party modules.

So I found this article [How do you add an in-app purchase to an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556336/how-do-you-add-an-in-app-purchase-to-an-ios-application) on Stack overflow.
Those answers were written in Swift or Objective-C, and I know little about Swift.

After I read about this article https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios.
I am thinking about making a method to request a purchase using Swift or Objective-C, and expose it to my React native project as a Native Module. After sending a request from a Button inside React Native View, I want to send the result to my React Native project using RCTEventEmitter from the Swift or Objective-C code.

Is it a good idea and how I can implement this?

Comment: Why u won't use a third-party module?

Comment: I want to understand how it's work and maintain it for myself. And I don't want to give any   security credentials like password when verifying a receipt to a third party module in my production app.

Comment: Actually, I'm using before [react-native-iap](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap) you can see how it works,
Anyway if you found anything useful tell me, please!